# How can I get access to Ancient Dust?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, cantrips, pathfinder-society

[Ancient Dust](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1261) seems to be an interesting and powerful cantrip.

How can I get access to it in Pathfinder Society play?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Adventure Paths are typically not allowable sources in PFS

When AoN gets around to it, they will add the [PFS Limited](https://2e.aonprd.com/PFS.aspx) tag to *ancient dust*. The [Character Options](https://paizo.com/pathfindersociety/characteroptions) page, "Using Options from Pathfinder Adventures or Adventure Paths" header specifies

> **Typically, characters cannot select options from a Pathfinder Adventure.** However, Chronicle Sheets from sanctioned Adventures or boons from the Achievement Points store often grant characters access to options from these Adventures.

In order to access *ancient dust*, you will either need a specific Boon that may or may not exist from special events... or wait for the spell to be published in a non-Adventure context.